# render component inside loop in react-native

Tags: loops, react-native

Can someone help me understand why renderPosesList() is not rendering the 'Text'. I get the value rendered if i uncomment 'Text' inside render().
this.renderPosesList() prints the data in console but i see a blank page on the screen. I added 'key' attribute looking at the other posts, but it didnt do the trick. 
*Eventually i'll be replacing Text with a custom component.*

```
renderPosesList() {
    return this.state.posesDictionary.forEach((pose, index) => {
    console.log("pose > " + index + " > " + pose.key);
    <Text key={index}>{pose.key}</Text>;
  });
}

render() {
  if (this.state.posesDictionary.length > 0) {
    let p = this.state.posesDictionary[0];
    return (
      <View>
        {/* <Text>{p.key}</Text> */}
        {this.renderPosesList()}
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Loading..</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forEach does not return a value use .map for returning HTML tag

```
 renderPosesList = () => {
    return this.state.posesDictionary.map((pose, index) => {
      console.log("pose > " + index + " > " + pose.key);
      return(
      <Text key={index}>{pose.key}</Text>
      );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
renderPosesList() {
    return this.state.posesDictionary.map((pose, index) => {
    console.log("pose > " + index + " > " + pose.key);
    return <Text key={index}>{pose.key}</Text>;
  });
}
```

What you have missed is you are not returning anything from your map function, you cannot have anything on your view unless it has been returned as a child of react node which in this case is

Comment: Please provide explanations for your answer.

Comment: i was using "forEach" instead of map, that was the issue. Thank you